# Prepared statement and null value when using?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a need to evaluate if a user logged in to a system after a specific date.  To do this, there are three tables in a MySQL database, users, survey and logins.  Survey holds the date of a point in time that needs compared against the users last log in.  Here's the question.

When I used the "?" placeholder, the resulting num_rows count was always 0.  But when I assign the values before handing the query statement to $mysqli->prepare(), the process works as expected.  Somehow, store_result() was not picking up the column. Here is my code:

```
 if (isset($userId)){
//get survey release date
$res3 = $mysqli->query("SELECT sur_date,sur_url FROM survey ORDER BY sur_id DESC limit 1");
$array = $res3->fetch_assoc();
$theta_date = $array['sur_date'];
//$theta_date = "2013-01-18 01:00:00";

   //this didn't generate errors, but didn't output the correct result either.
   //$query = "SELECT login_id FROM logins WHERE login_user=? AND login_date>=?";
   //if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
   // $stmt->bind_param('ss',$userID,$theda_date);
   // $stmt->execute();

  //this works
  $query = "SELECT login_id FROM logins WHERE login_user='$userId' AND login_date>='$theta_date'";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
    $stmt->execute() or die("The query did not work");

    //if number is greater than 0 do something
    $stmt->store_result();
      printf("The number of login ids after theta are %d",$stmt->num_rows);
  $stmt->close();
}else{
   echo "The query did not execute.";
}
 }else{
   echo "The User ID was not valid.";
   exit();
 }
 $mysqli->close();
```

Any insight would be helpful,

Comment: `$theta_date` `$theda_date` typo?

Comment: Thanks bmeswing, but it was typo in my post, not in the code.  Though I wouldn't put it past me.

Answer (score 0):

The prepared statement seems to be having an issue with the $theta_date datetime format. $theta_date is stored in the survey table as '2013-01-18 01:00:00'.  bind_param() was trying to parse $theta_date as a reference.  Here is the solution:

```
 //convert datetime to Unix timestamp with strtotime()
 $theta_date = $array['sur_date'];
 $timestamp = strtotime($theta_date);

 //In the prepared statement, use MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME function to convert timestamp
 $query = "SELECT login_id FROM logins WHERE login_user=? AND login_date>=FROM_UNIXTIME(?)";

 //changed the parameter types to integer and bound $timestamp to second placeholder
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
   $stmt->bind_param('ii',$userId,$timestamp);
   $stmt->execute();

//the rest is the same
 $stmt->store_result();
   printf("The number of login ids after theta are %d",$stmt->num_rows);
   $stmt->close();
}
```

That was a pain.